# Can I safely interpret the first struct member's address as that of the whole struct?

Tags: c, list, struct

I'm implementing my own list similar to one from Linux *list.h*, but don't want to bother with *container_of* thing.

I've read that C compiler is not allowed to reorder struct members, but is there a guarantee that the first member's offset is always zero?

Can I just impose a restriction that list head member must be declared first to be able to get the whole struct member simply by casting head address to the container type?

Comment: Yes the offset of the first member must always be zero. Any possible padding is added *after* so the next member ends up on a nice offset.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude will that be true even if I locate the struct on invalid address? for example a struct of word size is located on an odd address

Comment: @CIsForCookies yes.

Comment: The offsets of the structure members is fixed by the compiler and will never change.

Comment: @CIsForCookies "if I locate the struct on invalid address?" --> compiler failure or run-time UB.  Code should not locate a structure on an invalid address.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)

> **6.7.2.1 Structure and union specifiers**
>
> 15 . Within a structure object, the non-bit-field members and the units in which bit-fields
> reside have addresses that increase in the order in which they are declared. **A pointer to a
> structure object, suitably converted, points to its initial member** (or if that member is a
> bit-field, then to the unit in which it resides), **and vice versa**. There may be unnamed
> padding within a structure object, but not at its beginning.

<sup>Emphasis mine</sup>